# SVN: How to periodically move some changes from feature branch to trunk?

Tags: svn, branch, branching-and-merging, feature-branch

I've got a branch that I'm doing some re-factoring work on, and I'd like to periodically move some changes back to trunk.

That is to say, parts of the re-factoring work can be moved / cherry-picked to trunk as they complete.

Does svn support such a workflow?

The docs seem to indicate a "branch,syn,sync,sync,reintegrate-all,delete" pattern.
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html

In my case, I'd like to not only keep branch alive and but also avoid svn changes that could impact other developers.  (Such as screwing up the merge tracking so that future merges are difficult.)

I do see the section on "record only" merges, but I'm not sure if that that helps.

Comment: If you want to keep the branch, stick to `branch,syn,sync,sync` and omit `reintegrate-all,delete`. And `record only` does not port changes.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario OK, but then how do I get my periodic subset of  changes from the branch to the trunk?

Comment: I just added some clarifications because I wasn't sure of what your question is. Do you say "periodic" because you want to automate it?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario so at what point would changes move to truck?

Comment: That's like asking others when you should release your software...

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Unless I misunderstood your comment, the workflow you proposed only brings changes from the trunk to the branch.  That's the easy part.  This question is how, exactly, to move updates back to trunk _from_ the branch with out screwing with SVN's merge tracking.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand the question. You post a link to the exact chapter in the Subversion book that explains how to use the `merge` command to keep a branch in sync, and then ask if it's possible and safe. That feature was introduced in 1.5 (June 2008) and current version is 1.8. I guess it's safe enough. I've particularly being merging around since 1.5 and nothing got broken in my data. Sorry I cannot be more helpful.